# multi-series grouped line chart differentiate the legend

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

[image]

Here is a DOJO for the issue http://dojo.telerik.com/aweDi/2

I have a chart that I want to display two different lines for each grouped item.  The legend shows the same grouped item twice, once for each series, I need that grouped item named different for each series.  any clues how to do that?

```
$("#rightLine").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        data: ko.toJS(my.rightLine()),
        group: { field: "Grp_Value" },
        sort: {
            field: "MonthTrxDateFirst",
            dir: "asc"
        },

        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    date: {
                        type: "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        position: "top"
    },
    series: [{
        type: "line",
        field: col
    }
    , {
        type: "line",
        field: col2
    }
    ],
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "MonthTrxDateFirst",
        labels: {
            rotation: -90,
            dateFormats:
                {
                    minutes: "HH:mm",
                    hours: "HH:mm",
                    days: "dd/MM",
                    months: "MMM 'yy",
                    years: "yyyy"
                }
        }, type: "Date", baseUnit: "months",

        crosshair: {
            visible: true
        }
    },
    valueAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: ty
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: ty,
        background: "white",
        // template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
        template: tmplate
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the JSON of the data look like? Can you create a DOJO that reproduces this?

Comment: @ezanker here is a dojo  http://dojo.telerik.com/aweDi/2

Comment: Can you use the name field of the series: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/UROPo

Comment: wow, totally missed that, that'll work. thanks